# Iterate through Lists in a site and load results in a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint 2010 site with about 60 lists. I want to make a collection of the lists in the site and then load the results in a Dropdownlist. All this will be done in a SharePoint 2010 visual web part. Here is an illustration:

```
Lists
------------
List1
List2
List3
List4

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="wsDDL" />
```

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Prepare for close votes and comments. You're not proving to us that you've put any effort in this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your explanation you could do something like this.

```
    class MyListsOfLists
{
    public ObjectLists AllLists { get; set; }
}

class ObjectLists
{
    public List<Adult> Adults { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public List<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public List<House> Houses { get; set; }
}


class Adult
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}


class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}


class Dog
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}

class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModelYear { get; set; }
}

class House
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Built { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, this will definitely be helpful. The other question would be how would you use the ObjectsList class if you wanted to automatically add lists to  the class so that I wont have to manually add them when a new list is added to the site.